# Will twilio sticky sender fail if I release one of my twilio numbers from my message service?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, twilio

My Web Api application uses Twilio to send SMS to customers and I have a message service and associated Twilio phone numbers that have sticky sender enabled.

What I need to know is if I release one of these numbers(say I release the Twilio number 12345678 which was used to send multiple SMS's to 98787878) , how would sticky sender behave the next time when I send an SMS to the number 98787878 ?

FYI, I have other numbers still active in the messaging service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I just tested this with a messaging service. I had two numbers and sent myself a message from the service. It came from a number and I then verified that sending another message from the service would come from that number.

I then removed the number from the messaging service and sent another message. It arrived from the remaining number in my messaging service.

If you remove a number, sticky sender will pick a new number from your messaging service's pool and use that as the sticky sender from now on.